# Flutter-Getx: RxList<ModelA> modelA = <ModelA>[].obs; OBX() not catching the value

Tags: flutter-getx

I have two RxList values `RxList testA = [].obs;` `RxList<ModelA> testB = <ModelA>[].obs`.

After I tested both with

```
testA().add(incomingData);
testB().add(incomingData);

Obx(() {
   return Container(child: Text(controller.testA()[0].name))
})

Obx(() {
   return Container(child: Text(controller.testB()[0].name))
})
```

Only `testA` gets updated. Is there any way that I can make `RxList` with `<ModelA>` can be listened to as well? Or, do I have to just use `RxList` and then use `as` to assign the type?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `final testB = <ModelA>[].obs`, use `testB.add(incomingData)` to add a value and use

```
Obx(() {
      return Container(child: Text(controller.testB[0].name));
 })
```

to access the value of index 0.

But I think you are not updating the value of index 0. Instead you are adding to the existing list thus increasing the index.

You can use `.assgin(incomingData)` to replace instead.

Answer (score 0):

For a custom class like your `ModelA`, the `Obx` widget will not get updated unless you `refresh()` that `Rx<ModelA>`

You will need to refresh It manually like this:

```
testB.refresh();
```